# awsvpc: Network Configuration is not valid for the given networkMode of this task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

My task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "datadog" {
  family        = "${var.environment}-datadog-agent-task"
  task_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/datadog-role"

  container_definitions = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "${var.environment}-${var.datadog-identifier}",
    "network_mode" : "awsvpc",
    "image": "datadog/agent:latest",
    "portMappings": [
      {
...
```

My service defintion:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "datadog" {
  name            = "${var.environment}-${var.datadog-identifier}-datadog-ecs-service"
  cluster         = "${var.cluster}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.datadog.arn}"

  network_configuration {
    subnets = flatten(["${var.private_subnet_ids}"])
  }

  # This allows running one for every instance
  scheduling_strategy = "DAEMON"
}
```

I get the following error -

```
InvalidParameterException: Network Configuration is not valid for the given networkMode of this task definition
```

Is there something I am missing here? Looking at the Terraform docs and GitHub issues this should have worked. Is it related to running Datadog as a daemon?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the [`aws_ecs_task_definition`'s `network_mode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html#network_mode) to `awsvpc` if you are defining the `network_configuration` of the service that uses that task definition.

This is mentioned in the [documentation for the `network_configuration` parameter of the `aws_ecs_service` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html#network_configuration):

> `network_configuration` - (Optional) The network configuration for the
>   service. This parameter is required for task definitions that use the
>   `awsvpc` network mode to receive their own Elastic Network Interface,
>   and it is not supported for other network modes.

In your case you've added the `network_mode` parameter to the *container* definition instead of the *task* definition (a task is a collection of n containers and are grouped together to share some resources). The [container definition schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html) doesn't allow for a `network_mode` parameter.

Comment: I do if you notice above in the task definition.

Comment: You added it to the container definition which isn't valid. It needs to be in the task definition.

Comment: Doh! Thanks @ydaetskcoR ! Absolutely my fault. Can we choose to close this question since this was a bug in my code and not Terraform ?

Comment: Pretty much every question here is a big in people's code and not Terraform. The few that aren't that will direct people to the appropriate issue tracker on GitHub instead. Answers here are useful for other people who might make the same mistake or get the same error and aren't sure why.

Comment: As a side question - I want to run the datadog agent and an application on a single container as separate tasks each listening on different container ports.. Are there examples of multiple tasks on containers that might help me ?

Comment: As a follow up question to the above, if I want to run multiple tasks on a container, do they need to be a part of the same task definition ? Or can they be defined in separate task definitions and launched from 2 different service definitions ?

Comment: You should ask these as separate questions, not comments to another self contained question.